# Running SQL script using C# code ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
    public class ClassApp
    {
        static string ServerName = "LAPTOP-xxxxxxRK\\SQLEXPRESS";
        static string DatabaseName = "NewDbInstance";
        private SqlConnection tmpConn;

        public void CreateDb()
        {
            SqlConnection tmpConn;
            string sqlCreateDBQuery;
            tmpConn = new SqlConnection();
            tmpConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER = " + ServerName + "; Trusted_Connection=True;";
            sqlCreateDBQuery = " CREATE DATABASE " + DatabaseName;

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn);
            try
            {
                tmpConn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine(sqlCreateDBQuery);
                var result = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine("Database has been created successfully!");

                if (result == -1)
                {
                    RunScript(DatabaseName);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        public void RunScript(string dbName)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\script.sql");
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            script = script.Replace("GO", "");

            SqlConnection tmpConn;
            tmpConn = new SqlConnection();
            tmpConn.ConnectionString = "Server=LAPTOP-xxxxxxRK\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Database=" + dbName + "; Trusted_Connection=True;";
            tmpConn.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommandnew = new SqlCommand(script, tmpConn);
            var resultnew = myCommandnew.ExecuteNonQuery();   //Error comes here
            Console.WriteLine(resultnew);
            tmpConn.Close();
        }
```

So I have two questions

1. When I run this SQL file using C# I got the error

> 'CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first statement in a query batch.

How to solve this problem?

2. How to modify code like if create database if it does not exists?

Comment: observation: if your ASP.NET domain account has access to create databases: it is probably running with too many DB privileges - so *usually* I'd say "don't fix this" - create the databases separately, *not* in the website

Comment: Which line throws your error?

Comment: 9th Line of RunScript shows the error

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because some SQL DDL commands must be executed as the first statement of a SQL Batch, which is separated by "GO" statements in SSMS.

To run a script with "GO" statements, instead of parsing them out and creating other errors, use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo library.  It will process the script as separate batches without you having the messy problem of removing "GO" from already existing scripts.

Your code would look very similar to:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = ...)
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

            try
            {
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but when I do this It gives me new error

'Cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.IRenewable.Token''

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that.  The SqlConnection is a plain ol' ADO.Net SqlConnection object with a valid connection string on it.  It doesn't even need to be open but you should make sure that the connection string will open the connection.  If you post your code I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hello @kgw thanks for the quick response I am adding my new git repo for the code and let me know where I am doing mistake 

It will be a great help for me 
Btw I am using asp net core 3.1 version of dot net core

Comment: https://github.com/John786007/SqlDemo

Repo For the code
@kgw

Comment: The nuget packages for Smo are not very complete.  I used the following to get the correct references:

Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo -Version 150.18097.0-xplat
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Tools.Sql.BatchParser -Version 150.18097.0-xplat
At that point I was getting the same error which is very odd since passing in a SqlConnection object is a valid constructor per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.-ctor?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Common_ServerConnection__ctor

Comment: This fixes it in your code:
                tmpConn.ConnectionString = "Server=LAPTOP-Pxxxxxxx\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Database=" + dbName + "; Trusted_Connection=True;";

                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(tmpConn.ConnectionString));

                try
                {
                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

Comment: Note that you no longer need to clean out the "GO" statements so you can get rid of the regex.  And you can run interesting SQL scripts like:
`code`
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[myfunction]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsScalarFunction') = 1)
 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE Function [dbo].[myfunction]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
 RETURN -1  -- function stub
END
GO

--------------------------------------  ALTER FUNCTION--------------------------------------
SET NOEXEC OFF
GO


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[myfunction]
-- actual function...
`code`

Comment: @Jhon If that fixes your issue please consider crediting me with the answer.

Comment: Hello @kgw I tried as per your instruction but Now I am getting 

Failed to connect to Server

Network or Instance related error

Comment: @Jhon OK, it's probably your connection string.  You obscured the servername in the Git repo. I didn't change it so it's probably just a copy-paste error.  It should be the same connection that is in your Main() method.

Comment: No I change the connection string as well but still Same error Message

Do we need to configure ssms for such kind of operation through code...?@kgw

Comment: Hello @kgw I modified the previous code mentioned by you.
thanks

Comment: @Jhon I've duplicated and solved the problem on my end.  Your using .Net Core which is new to me.  I solved the problem when I found this article:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/
Remove your reference to System.Data.SqlClient and change add reference to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead.  Clean up the references and my original code above works like a charm.  Also, you can put your connection object creation into using... statements so your connection objects get properly disposed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help 

I follow your way and yes now I am able to connect my database as well as execute the sql query also.

But when I use same code in Aws Lamda Function then it is creating problem for me

I am getting error

Could not load file or assemble.
But still thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Jhon, I'm glad it's working for you. Please credit me with the answer.

Comment: @Jhon, you never mentioned the need to do Aws Lamba Functions in your original question.  You will have be deploy the referenced DLLs onto whatever environment you are using.  If are able to deploy your compiled DLL you should be able to deploy the referenced DLLs.  You might be able to merge the referenced DLLs with the ILMerge utility, which is part of the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

2. Run script to check whether the database exists

```
    DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
    SET @dbname = N'DatabaseName'

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname 
    OR name = @dbname)))
```

Comment: This is the script code..? which will replace my sqlCreateDBQuery...?